# How to get checkbox in first column of QTableView in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qabstracttablemodel

In my QTableView, I am trying to have first column of checkboxes but i am getting all the row columns filled with checkboxes and also all of them are checked by default. I am not able to changed the state of checkboxes either.

```
class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, listData=[[]], headers=[], parent=None):
        super(MyTableModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.__listData = listData
        self.__headers = headers


    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        value = self.__listData[row][column]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            if self.__listData[row] == 0:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            else:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return value
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return value
```

Comment: have you considered using a `QStandardItemModel` (populated by `QStandardItem`s) instead of creating your own model? It gives you a lot of this behaviour for free, and is recommended unless you have a specific need to create a custom model.

Comment: well, I have not jumped directly to this stage, I have a specific need so for the rows that have checkbox checked gets to stay and unchecked what gets clear or not processed.

Comment: I get the requirements of the checkbox. I'm saying that functionality is implemented in `QStandardItemModel` already if you were to use it. My question is, do you need functionality which is not in `QStandardItemModel`? If you do, it is probably a good idea to detail them and include them in your code snippet so they can be incorporated into answers to the question. If you don't, then I would suggest switching to `QStandardItemModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came across this question. Not sure you found the answer.
To answer your question, if you want the check boxes only for the first column, you will need return `QtCore.Qt.Unchecked` or `QtCore.Qt.Checked` only for `index` with `column == 0`. So, you can change your code to:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    row = index.row()
    column = index.column()
    value = self.__listData[row][column]

    if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole and column == 0:
        if self.__listData[row] == 0:
            return QtCore.QVariant(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
    if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        return value
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return value
```

And, you can check if the `index` is in `self.__listData` and return `QtCore.Qt.Unchecked` or `QtCore.Qt.Checked` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't now about PyQT but think there is no difference with c++Qt.
You need to override `Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractItemModel::flags(const QModelIndex & index) const` and return for your checkable column `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable`.